# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop fails to load after 2nd GPU added; Windows 10 AOK

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, graphics

I built a multi-GPU PC machine for personal deep learning research with Ubuntu, with:

- Intel I9-9900K CPU (LGA1151)
- Four each, Corsair Vengence RGB Pro 16MB RAM
- [Asus WS Z390 PRO motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/WS-Z390-PRO/overview/)
- Two each, [ASUS GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Turbo GPU](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/TURBO-RTX2080TI-11G/)
- SSD 1: Samsung 970 EVO M.2 1 TB
- SSD 2: HP EX950 M.2 1 TB (Windows 10 installed here)
- Deepcool 120mm fan 0.23A RF 120M x5
- Lian Li 120mm fan x2
- Redux 80 Noctua NF-R8 redux 1800 PWM
- Lian Li PC-011 Air case
- EVGA SuperNOVA T2 1600 PSU
- Masterliquid ML360R RGB CPU cooler

The second GPU came in late, so I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with only one GPU; set up the NVIDIA driver, CUDA, and Tensorflow (with GPU), and it works.

Installed the second GPU when it came in, and tried to boot Ubuntu; I get the login prompt for the desktop, enter my password, but then the system just hangs withe a purple background and my cursor (not able to move it any more).

I can boot Ubuntu in safe mode with no GUI, and can run commands there.

[nvidia-smi](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface) shows both of the GPUs.  Everything is fine in Windows 10, I can see the second GPU fine.

Anyone have a clue as to what the issue might be? BTW, I am an Ubuntu newbie.

How do I troubleshoot enabling Ubuntu to boot with two GPUs?

The contents of /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    23.741] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-1764.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[    23.741] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    23.741] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    23.741] Current Operating System: Linux anduril 5.0.0-29-generic #31~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 18:29:21 UTC 2019 x86_64
[    23.741] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-generic root=UUID=cd06c7e7-bb97-489c-bb2d-eedf4a02076b ro quiet splash resume=UUID=f2d52073-433f-4803-bcd7-4e8e85b3a6d3 vt.handoff=1
[    23.741] Build Date: 02 May 2019  08:06:54AM
[    23.741] xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3~18.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    23.741] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    23.741]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    23.741] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    23.741] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Sep 30 01:22:05 2019
[    23.741] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    23.741] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    23.742] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    23.742] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    23.742] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    23.743] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    23.743] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    23.743] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    23.743] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    23.743] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    23.743] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    23.743] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    23.743] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    23.743] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    23.743]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.743] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    23.743]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.743] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    23.743]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.743] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    23.743]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.743] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    23.743]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    23.743] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    23.743] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.743] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    23.743] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    23.743] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    23.743] (II) Loader magic: 0x56118df71020
[    23.743] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    23.743]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    23.743]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[    23.743]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    23.743]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    23.743] (++) using VT number 2

[    23.744] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32
[    23.744] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    23.745] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 12 paused 0
[    23.745] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card2)
[    23.745] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card2 226:2 fd 13 paused 0
[    23.745] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    23.745] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 14 paused 0
[    23.746] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.746] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" ModulePath extended to "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.746] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg,/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.746] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" ModulePath extended to "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg,/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    23.746] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" setting /dev/dri/card1 as PrimaryGPU
[    23.747] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:3e98:1043:8694 rev 2, Mem @ 0xb3000000/16777216, 0x70000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    23.747] (--) PCI: (3@0:0:0) 10de:1e04:1043:8675 rev 161, Mem @ 0xb6000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    23.747] (--) PCI:*(4@0:0:0) 10de:1e04:1043:8675 rev 161, Mem @ 0xb4000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00003000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    23.747] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    23.748] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    23.749] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.749]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.749]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    23.749] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    23.749] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[    23.752] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    23.752]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.752]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    23.752] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:52:10 CDT 2019
[    23.752] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    23.752] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:1
[    23.753] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    23.753] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    23.753] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    23.753] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.753]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.753]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    23.753] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    23.753] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    23.753] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    23.754] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.754]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.754]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    23.754] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    23.754] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    23.754] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    23.755] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:2
[    23.755] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    23.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    23.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    23.755] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    23.755] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" options to /dev/dri/card1
[    23.755] (II) Applying OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" options to /dev/dri/card1
[    23.755] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
[    23.755] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
[    23.755] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    23.755] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[    23.755] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[    23.755] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-430/xorg/libglxserver_nvidia.so
[    23.771] (II) Module glxserver_nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    23.771]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[    23.771]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    23.771] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:50:01 CDT 2019
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:4:0:0
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[    23.804] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
[    23.806] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce RTX 2080 Ti (TU102-A) at PCI:4:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 11534336 kBytes
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 90.02.17.00.b2
[    23.806] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.806] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    23.806] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    23.806] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    23.806] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(0): No enabled display devices found; starting anyway because
[    23.806] (--) NVIDIA(0):     AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration is enabled
[    23.807] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    23.807] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
[    23.807] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[    23.807] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[    23.807] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-1 at PCI:3:0:0
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[    23.834] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: disconnected
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: disconnected
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: disconnected
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-3: disconnected
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-4: disconnected
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-5: disconnected
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.835] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): 
[    23.878] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): NVIDIA GPU GeForce RTX 2080 Ti (TU102-A) at PCI:3:0:0 (GPU-1)
[    23.878] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Memory: 11534336 kBytes
[    23.878] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-1): VideoBIOS: 90.02.17.00.b2
[    23.878] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-1): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    23.879] (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    23.879] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    23.897] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[    23.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    23.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    23.912] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    23.913] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    23.913] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "PrimaryGPU" is not used
[    23.913] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    23.913] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    23.913] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    23.913] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    23.913] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[    23.913] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension Present
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[    23.914] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    23.914] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[    23.914] (II) GLX: Another vendor is already registered for screen 0
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[    23.914] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[    23.915] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[    23.915] (II) Initializing extension NV-GLX
[    23.915] (II) Initializing extension NV-CONTROL
[    23.940] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    23.940] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.940] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    23.940] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    23.941] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.941]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 0.28.1
[    23.941]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    23.941]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    23.941] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    23.941] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 46 paused 0
[    23.941] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    23.941] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    23.941] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.941] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.941] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    23.941] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    23.941] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    23.941] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    23.941] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.941] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.941] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.941] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    23.942] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event8)
[    23.942] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.942] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    23.942] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event8 13:72 fd 49 paused 0
[    23.942] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    23.942] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[    23.942] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.942] (II) event8  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.942] (II) event8  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    23.942] (II) event8  - Video Bus: device removed
[    23.942] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8/event8"
[    23.942] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    23.942] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.942] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.942] (II) event8  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.942] (II) event8  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    23.943] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    23.943] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.943] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    23.943] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 50 paused 0
[    23.943] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    23.943] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    23.943] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.943] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.943] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    23.943] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    23.943] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[    23.943] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    23.943] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.943] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.943] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.943] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    23.943] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    23.943] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    23.943] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    23.944] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event0 13:64 fd 51 paused 0
[    23.944] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    23.944] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    23.944] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    23.944] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.944] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    23.944] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    23.944] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0/event0"
[    23.944] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    23.944] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.944] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.944] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    23.944] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    23.944] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event21)
[    23.944] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.944] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.944] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event22)
[    23.944] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.944] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event23)
[    23.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event24)
[    23.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event25)
[    23.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event26)
[    23.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event27)
[    23.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event28)
[    23.945] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.945] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.

... had to trim to fit under the 30000 char forum post limit

[    23.954] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.954] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.963] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.965] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    23.965] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.966] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    23.973] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    24.350] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Comment: Did you look at the xorg.log?

Answer (score 0):

Until you post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` there really isn't much anyone can do with your question. There's not enough information provided to diagnose the problem.

From the general description, this fits. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1003017/how-do-i-set-one-gpu-for-display-and-the-other-two-gpus-for-cuda-computing-/

and it appears to be unresolved.

BTW you could purchase a used Tesla M40 12GB GPU for under $400 on ebay which is more than enough juice to do machine learning. Furthermore today's Intel CPU/Motherboard combos are price/performance inferior when compared to AMD. Especially when it comes to IO bandwidth. AM4 has PCIe-4.0, which has ridiculous IO bandwidth.

You could have bought a threadripper 1950X 16 cores/32 threads @ 4Ghz for the same price as your 8/16 Intel CPU. BTW, these CPUs support OpenCL, but more to the point, ML tends to be a "scale out" problem not a "scale up". A TR workstation (or a high end AM4 workstation board) motherboard would give you the IO expansion you need to add multiple GGPUs as your needs grow.

It would also buy you more memory expansion room, 2TiB max.

You could also dump the dual boot situation entirely with that many cores and clocks and run the Win10 VM with a dedicated video card via VFIO which would get you near native performance. Level 1 Techs did a good video on it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLy1n7X2cAU

and when you're not using the VM, the system can have it back for computes.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating xorg.conf seemed to do the trick, I have my desktop back now.

so:

sudo X -configure

sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf

After a restart I have my desktop back, at least when connected to the motherboard's HDMI (using the intel graphics). Before it was just blank after login gui.

Also nvidia-smi sees both of the Nvidia gpus as well.